# Convert NSMutableAttributedString to NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, uilabel, nsmutableattributedstring

Can we not convert `NSMutableAttributedString` to `NSString`?

I have two `NSMutableAttributedStrings` and I am appending the 2nd string onto 1st as below:

`[string1 appendAttributedString:string2];`

Since I have to display string1 on a label I do:

```
self.label1.text = (NSString *)string1;
```

I am getting `"unrecognized selector sent to instance"` error.

Am I doing anything wrong here? Isn't this the correct way to assign a `NSMutableAttributedString` to text property of a label?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You can't use a cast to convert an object from one type to another. Use the provided method:

```
label1.text = [string1 string];
```

Better yet, use the attributed string:

```
label1.attributedText = string1
```

Comment: Yeah I just realized the label has attributedText property as well. Thanks for the reply though!! :)

Answer (score 26):

`NSAttributtedString` includes a `.string` property. From there, you can take `NSString` without attributes.

So:

```
NSAttributtedString* someString;
NSString* string = someString.string;
```

Comment: You saved me buddy. sorry stackoverflow does not allow me to upvote this more than one.

Comment: I agree.  I wish I could upvote more than once.  This greatly simplified my code.

Answer (score 0):

NSAttributtedString have a property string and it is read only property you can not change it.

```
NSAttributtedString* attributtedString;
NSString* plainString = attributtedString.string;
```

Answer (score -1):

Apart from @rmaddy's answer, mine case is different here.

Actually I used `NSMutableAttributedString` in JSON parsing to send details on server.

At parsing time I got exception because `NSMutableAttributedString` contains information about other attributes too, like `color space`. Because of that it wont parse.

I tried many other ways but finally got solution to get string using below code:

```
// "amountString" is NSMutableAttributedString string object

NSMutableAttributedString *mutableString = (NSMutableAttributedString *)amountString;
amountValueString = [mutableString string];
amountValueString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", amountString];

NSRange fullRange = NSMakeRange(0, amountString.length);
NSAttributedString *attStr = [mutableString attributedSubstringFromRange:fullRange];
NSDictionary *documentAttributes = @{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSPlainTextDocumentType};

NSData *textData = [attStr dataFromRange:fullRange documentAttributes:documentAttributes error:NULL];
NSString *amountValueString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:textData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```